# How to set selected area of Image to ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

I Was trying to set image to image`imageview`view from external storage and I done with that, but the thing is that it sets the whole image to `imageview` and I only want to set the selected square area from that image. Just life facebook provided functionality to set profile pic..
Can any one help me to do it??
Following is the sample what i want to do..

[image]

Comment: you mean you want to crop image?

Comment: use this with your camera intent - photoPickerIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");

Comment: I don't want to modify the original image, I just want to set selected area to imageview

Comment: use scale type "matrix"

Comment: @pskink can you explain it with small example, please. I don't know how to do it..

Comment: imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX); imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix)

Comment: @pskink thanks but the link provided by peliken fulfill my requirements...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public static Bitmap cropBitmapToSquare(Bitmap bmp) {

    System.gc();
    Bitmap result = null;
    int height = bmp.getHeight();
    int width = bmp.getWidth();
    if (height <= width) {
        result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, (width - height) / 2, 0, height,
                height);
    } else {
        result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, (height - width) / 2, width,
                width);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here is a sample with crop activity:

http://khurramitdeveloper.blogspot.ru/2013/07/capture-or-select-from-gallery-and-crop.html

Answer (score 0):

actually my comment above about setImageMatrix was not the best solution, try this custom Drawable (no need to allocate any temporary Bitmaps):

```
class CropDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {

    private Rect mSrc;
    private RectF mDst;

    public CropDrawable(Bitmap b, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super(b);
        mSrc = new Rect(left, top, right, bottom);
        mDst = new RectF(0, 0, right - left, bottom - top);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(getBitmap(), mSrc, mDst, null);
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicWidth() {
        return mSrc.width();
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicHeight() {
        return mSrc.height();
    }
}
```

and testing code:

```
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test);
    Drawable d = new CropDrawable(b, 150, 100, 180, 130);
    iv.setImageDrawable(d);
    setContentView(iv);
```